# Assigning variables with = isn't working as usual

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a class where I instantiate with a choice of variables, either individually inputting x, y, z, or inputting an array, r, which I store in a numpy array. The behaviour I'm trying to get is that when you have

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
a[0] = 4
print(a[0], b[0])
```

and you get the output of 4, 4, as expected. But I have the following code

```
import numpy as np

class FourVector():
    def __init__(self, ct = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, r = np.array([])):
        self.ct = ct
        self.r = r
        self.x = self.r[0]
        self.y = self.r[1]
        self.z = self.r[2]

a = FourVector(r=[1,2,3])
a.r[0] = 5
print(a.r[0], a.x)
```

and it outputs 5, 1. I can't figure out why. Searching around, the closest I can find to an answer is that it's due to the differences between mutable/immutable objects. If that's the case, I don't understand where it comes in to play here.

Comment: You're ahead of the game, many people expect it to work the opposite.

Comment: If you'd like a deeper understanding, read the first section of the [data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html). Assignment in Python is quite simple, actually, but is confusing at first if you are coming from a C-like language.

Answer (score 1):

I think Approaching Darkness Fi's answer with pointer diagrams is somewhat helpful, but also misleading and incomplete. When you are dealing with containers like lists, you'll have two levels of pointers involved, one from a variable to the list, and a second layer from the list to its contents. This is important to understand why your two examples don't work the same way

Lets lay out a simple scenario that combines both examples into one:

```
a = [1]
b = a
x = a[0]
```

Here's what points to what in this situation:

```
a
 \
  <list object> ---> 1
 /                  /
b                  /
                  /
x ----------------
```

There are two objects, the integer `1` and the list. The variables `a` and `b` both point to the list, while `x` points directly to the integer.

Now,  lets see what happens when you change this initial situation by doing `a[0] = 5`:

```
a
 \
  <list object> ---> 5
 /              
b               

x ---> 1
```

The variables all remain pointed at the same objects they were pointing to before, but the list has been modified to have its first element point to a different integer than it used to. This is why you'll get the same result if you print `a` and `b`, but different results if you print `a[0]` and `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `a.x` doesn't point to `a.r[0]`. This is absolutely because `a.r[0]` is immutable.

The difference is this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a            # a is mutable, so b now points to a
a[0] = 4         # change a, so you change b
print(a[0], b[0])
```

Versus:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a[0]         # a[0] is immutable, so copy it and point b at it
a[0] = 4         # change a, which DOESN'T CHANGE b
print(a[0], b[0])
```

If this is something you actually need, try this:

```
class FourVector():
    def __init__(self, ct = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, r = np.array([])):
        self.ct = ct
        self.r = r

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.r[0]
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.r[1]
    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.r[2]
```

Properties are methods that act like attributes, so you can call `a.x`, it will run the `FourVector.x` method and return the result. Note that you *cannot* do `a.x = some_value` without a bit more code

```
    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self.r[0] = val
    # etc
```

Comment: So would I be in the right ballpark by suggesting immutable objects are ones that, for assigning, makes a copy, and mutable objects actually point to one another?

Comment: @user4496239 That's the right ballpark, yes. Technically ***ALL*** objects are copied by reference, but when you do `x = r[0]` you're pointing `x` at the reference for the integer `1`, not the reference to the first element in `r`.

Comment: @user4496239 it does APPEAR that way, however, because if you'd done something like `r = [['sub','list'], 2, 3]`, `a = r[0]`, `r[0][0].insert(0, "another")` then `a == ['another', 'sub', 'list]`. Just remember that assignment changes that, e.g. `r[0][0] = ["another", "sub", "list"]` would leave `a == ["sub", "list"]`

Comment: I think this answer's comments about mutability are completely wrong. While mutablility can occaisionally matter for assignments (e.g. after `a += b` does `a` refer to the same object or not), it doesn't in the situation described in the question. Even if `r[0]` was a mutable object like a list, if you reassigned it (rather than mutating the sub-value), you'd still end up with different values in `r[0]` and `x`. That said, your suggestion of using properties to implement the `x`, `y` and `z` attributes is a very good one.

Comment: @Blckknght absolutely correct. I tried to clarify in the comments, but I feel like the simplified "mutable = reference, immutable = copy" works well enough for a ballpark answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, python always copies by reference, and `int` objects are references. So when you write:

```
 self.x = self.r[0]
```

You copy the `int` reference in `self.r[0]` into `self.x`. But when you write:

```
a.r[0] = 5
```

You have placed a new reference in the `r[0]` of your object, so `a.r[0]` and `a.x` no longer the same object. Here's a pointer diagram:

Before assignment:

> a.x    ---> None
>   a.r[0] ---> None

Assign `a.r`:

> a.x    ---> None
>   a.r[0] ---> int(1)

Copy to `a.x`:

> a.x    ---> int(1)
>   a.r[0] ---> int(1)

Note that the two variables refer to the same object, but they have no link **to each other**. Therefore, after second assignment:

> a.x    ---> int(1)
>   a.r[0] ---> int(5)